# Quantum Espresso: Select number of valence electrons

Tags: quantum-espresso

I want to calculate the transition levels of charged defect using Quantum Espresso, I want to know if there's something analogous to NELECT and NUPDOWN in QE like in VASP?

Comment: I believe it's tot_charge and tot_magnetization

Comment: Did you figure this out? Is your comment correct? If so, please write an answer! It will be helpful to future users :)

Comment: I still haven't figure this out

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been almost 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? I did not see your reply to my question in May 2023 because you did not use the @ character to ping me.

Comment: @NikeDattani thank you for your suggestion; I've just known this ping feature